# which compilers give longest long double

Tags: c++, double, long-double

I may be doing something very stupid here, but i've reached the limit of what double can achieve and on my compiler (i'm using newest xcode on a mac) long double seems no better.

I've read elsewhere that the length of long double depends on the compiler, if so what would you guys recommend i work with to give the longest long doubl1

Comment: You could try something like GMP for arbitrary precision.

Comment: [link](http://OpenMP.org)

Comment: @Dru: Your link is to OpenMP which doesn't address this question.

Comment: you're right.  OpenMP's got nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/), based on [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), is for multiple-precision floating-point computations with correct rounding.